# value={input} doesn't update in TextInput component (Android)

Tags: react-native, textinput

I have a TextInput component:

```
<TextInput
        ref={refInput}
        onKeyPress={(e) => handleOnKeyPress(e.nativeEvent.key)}
        style={defaultStyles.input}
        value={input}
        maxLength={1}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        onFocus={onFocus}
      />
```

This is my handleOnKeyPress:

```
const handleOnKeyPress = (key: string) => {
    if (key === 'Backspace') {
      if (input === '') {
        onKeyAction('back');
      } else {
        setInput('');
      }
    } else {
      setInput(key.toUpperCase());
      onKeyAction('forward');
    }
  };
```

What do I expect: typing in this TextInput rewrites everything that's inside with the key just pressed.

What I got (just in Android, iOS works fine): pressing a key with cursor before the already written letter deletes it and moves the cursor to the next TextInput, instead pressing it after doesn't edit anything and only moves the cursor.

input is a useState Hook variable

Comment: My mi9t and android studio pixel3 emulator (macOS)

Comment: I know that, tested with software keyboard